# Should I book Air Berlin in advance given the ongoing take over?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I heard that Air Berlin is not capable of funding itself after Etihad backed out, and Lufthansa is in the process of taking it over.

I am wondering if it is advisable to book three months in advance during this ongoing chaos.

If I book in advance can those tickets be cancelled?

Comment: What if the takeover doesn't happen or gets delayed? Your flights might just not happen, and you blew your money.

Comment: Air Berlin has no cash and govt. has injected some cash. Takeover is inevitable.

Comment: What do you mean by "in advance"? In air ticketing, "advance" means "after today". Buying an AB ticket for travel tomorrow morning is a risk profile I would live with. Three months ahead is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Calchas : I have updated the question, its 3 months in advance.

Comment: As a note: Last month, I had a flight with Air Berlin, the first leg of which being 2 hours late (the leg flight length was one hour), causing me to miss all my connections... and they lost my luggage to boot. A 6-hour journey became a 15-hour one. On the return flight, they were about 40 minutes late, giving me about 15 minutes to get to my connection gate. I've never had any of these things happen before in my life. **Book at your own risk**... or perhaps their service might improve after being taken over?

Comment: Lots of Air Berlin flights getting delayed or canceled these days. I'd only take them if they have an amazing deal and you don't really care about getting to your destination or not. Otherwise don't.

Comment: https://www.airberlin.com/en/site/landingpages/flight_information.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it stands now, Air Berlin is in insolvency proceedings. Competitors are trying to buy various *parts* of the airline, but anti-trust laws might stop any one competitor from buying the entire company.

I wouldn't pay much in advance of the flight. If the flight does not happen, any claims against the airline might be tied up in the insolvency proceedings, and repaid only late and in part.

Answer (score 6):

In general you should avoid making *any* business with an insolvent company. If there is *any* problem which results in them getting in debt to you (like owing you a refund or compensation), they are actually *forbidden* from paying you directly. You will be put on the list of creditors and won't get a cent until the liquidation is over. And when there is not enough left after they paid their debts to those who have priority (and among those is anyone they owed money to before declaring bankruptcy), you might not get all the money they owe you.